# Can we use differenced logarithms of variables when checking for cointegration?

Tags: time-series, data-transformation, cointegration, logarithm

Is it possible to use the difference (D) of the natural logarithms of variables when checking for cointegration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\Delta$ denote the difference operator, i.e. $\Delta x_t:=x_{t}-x_{t-1}$.

If you want to investigate presence of cointegration between $\Delta\log(y)$ and $\Delta\log(x)$, you would first need both $\Delta\log(y)$ and $\Delta\log(x)$ to be integrated. Then if there exists a coefficient $\beta$ such that the linear combination $\Delta\log(y)+\beta\Delta\log(x)$ is stationary you find presence of cointegration, while if no such $\beta$ exists there is no cointegration.

Meanwhile, if $\Delta\log(y)$ and $\Delta\log(x)$ are stationary while $\log(y)$ and $\log(x)$ are integrated, then $\Delta\log(y)$ and $\Delta\log(x)$ cannot be cointegrated by definition so there is no point in investigating this possibility. In such a case you may inspect cointegration between $\log(y)$ and $\log(x)$ instead.

Comment: Thanks, but if there exist no cointegration between log(y) and log(x) what should be my next step in my model analysis?

Comment: @LionelMbanda, this has been discussed in other posts on Cross Validated, you may search for them. Briefly, you may model $\Delta\log(y)$ and $\Delta\log(x)$ as a vector autoregression or a simple regression, it really depends on the context and your modelling goals.

Comment: I want to check the relationship between the variables

Comment: @LionelMbanda, Depending on what relationship you want to check, you would choose a different model to estimate. You could start with just estimating the correlation between the diff-logs of x and y.

Comment: @LionelMbanda, I see you have posted another question on further modelling of the data, which is good, so we can finish this thread. If you find the answer satisfactory, you may click on the tick mark to the left to accept it. If the answer is not clear, you are welcome to ask for clarification. This is how Cross Validated works. (Your follow-up questions in the comments should actually belong in a new thread.)

Comment: Thank you very much, I am working with three variables and 35 observations, of yearly data time series. I want to check causality relationship between these variables. The 3 variables are all stationary after first difference by using ADF and Philip Perrons test & not cointegrated. I am really confused don`t know how to move from here, i don`t know if my methodology used for this work is correct or not and how move forward having stationary variables at first difference and no cointegration with data at levels. How can i do to proceed with the analysis of my model. Please i need help, thanks.